# How to use group_by%>%sum for some of the columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have this dataframe df as an example

```
`df = data.frame(x = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),
                y = 1:10,
                z = 11:20,
                n = 21:30)
```

I wish to sum the column y and z based on the groups of x while the column n stays the same with no changes. The desired output is as follows

```
   x  y  z  n
1  1 15 65 21
2  1 15 65 22
3  1 15 65 23
4  1 15 65 24
5  1 15 65 25
6  2 40 90 26
7  2 40 90 27
8  2 40 90 28
9  2 40 90 29
10 2 40 90 30
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(across(y:z, sum), .by = x)` (with dplyr >= 1.1.0).

Comment: Do you just want `df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(across(y:z, sum))`?

Comment: Yes thank you. Can you add the answer to the ansew section for futur readers ?